# Is it possible to share framebuffer objects between instances in Vulkan?

Tags: ubuntu, framebuffer, vulkan

I am trying to write a simple compositor.  Is it possible in Vulkan to access a data object (framebuffer, image, or buffer) from a different instance. (i.e. pass the handle to another process).  I am using Ubuntu and am trying to do this without using X, wayland, etc. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Vulkan objects are grouped into a strict hierarchy. The object which was used to create an object owns it, and generally speaking, the object which was created can no longer be used if you destroy the object that was used to create it.

For example, `vkAllocateMemory` takes a `VkDevice`. That memory object is allocated from that logical device, and it is bound to it. If that device is destroyed, you can't use it anymore. And if that device doesn't belong to your application, you can't use it either.

Now that being said, the `KHR_external_memory` extension (and its family of variations) allows for Vulkan to access memory between devices. This works even across processes; you can have two processes that create local logical devices that use physical devices with the same `VkPhysicalDeviceIDPropertiesKHR::deviceUUID`. These logical devices can share memory with one another, but this requires using a special struct to dictate that it will be shared.

Note that this sharing only works for logical devices that represent the same physical device through `deviceUUID`.